# Graphics in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, form-load

When the form is loading shouldn't the **CreateGraphics()** return a graphics object?

I mean, on the Form1_Load event can I write for example the following?

```
Graphics x;
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    x = this.CreateGraphics();
}
```

If not, then WHY?

I thought that when you create a new form, the [constructor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructor_%28object-oriented_programming%29) initiates the all object of the form. So why not also the graphics object?

I'm asking that, because when I'm trying to draw - on form_load, it doesn't show me what I draw.

The main reason is: I want to create a game, which have a board - so when the user click on the new game - first - I'm initiating the board and drawing it.
And in the **onPaint** event I just want to draw the current state of the board. So I thought the the initial state of the board should be draw on the **formLoad** event.

Comment: You would want to create a method that performs that draw.  Then inside your Constructor you would invoke that method.  That way at the creation of that class your draw is invoked.  I don't have time to provide an example, but later I'll demonstrate if a good answer isn't provided.

Comment: Looks like you need to read this rather lovely [FAQ](http://www.bobpowell.net/gdiplus_faq.htm)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not use the Graphics object in this manner; you should enclose each usage of it in a using block, or otherwise make sure you dispose of it after each set of drawing operations. Your code here will leave an unnecessary Graphics object hanging around.

Brief example:

```
private void MyonPaintOverload()
{
    using(Graphics x = this.CreateGraphics())
    {
        // draw here...
    }
}
```

Also, drawing on `Form_Load()` won't work, because the window is not actually visible at that point; there's nothing to draw on, basically.

Yes, you generally need to redraw the *whole thing* each cycle - because something as simple as another window being dragged across your window will 'wipe out' your drawing, and when it's invalidated by the other window being moved away, you need to redraw *everything* that you manually drew.

Comment: so lets say I have two circles on that board. so if I'm changing
one of the circle position, I need to redraw all the board? 
it's not very efficient, no? 
Ok, but I understood and accept your answer, because you're right.

Comment: @Elior Yes; you have to redraw the whole board; in fact, you have to start by wiping the whole form, first; otherwise remnants of your old circles could still be there.

Comment: @LeeTaylor What *is* a `Grapics` object, anyway?! hehe (thanks for the catch!)

Comment: The code snippet in this answer is fundamentally wrong, the window is not visible yet at the Load event.

Comment: @HansPassant I removed the `Load` event method title from my original answer. I am also going to edit my notes about `Form_Load` to make that more clear/

Comment: @AndrewBarber - No worries, you also had the braces around the wrong way too!